# Filtering data, comma vs not comma

Tags: r, filtering

I have the following code

```
#abnormal return 
exp.ret <- lm((RET-rf)~mkt.rf+smb+hml, data=tesla[tesla$period=="estimation.period",])
tesla$abn.ret <- (tesla$RET-tesla$rf)-predict(exp.ret,tesla)

#CAR during event window
CAR <- sum(tesla$abn.ret[tesla$period=="event.period",])
```

First section runs fine, but second gets this error:

> "Error in tesla$abn.ret[tesla$period == "event.period", ] :
> incorrect number of dimensions

I know that the solution is to remove the last comma:

```
  #CAR during event window
    CAR <- sum(tesla$abn.ret[tesla$period=="event.period"])
```

Just wondering what is the right pedagogical way of understanding it, why do I need a comma in the end in some cases, but some not, when I'm filtering for only parts of the data frame.

Comment: If you look at the documentation with command `?'['`, you find that the default behaviour of syntax `x[i]` is to drop one dimension away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` sign, `[[]]` and `[]` have different meanings.

In short:

- `$` sign and `[[]]` subsets **one column** of a dataframe or **one item** of a list.

  - The output of a subsetted dataframe will be a vector, while the output of a subsetted list will be a variable the same class as the original item, which can be a dataframe, another list, etc...
  - It's important to note that `$` doesn't accept a column index (only a column name) and that you cannot insert two column names/index after `$` or inside `[[]]`.
- `[]` slices a dataframe or a list sorting out **one or more** elements.

  - the class of the output variable will be the same as the original variable.
  - if you slice a dataframe using `[]`, the output will be a dataframe, the same applies for lists, etc...

In your specific case, you used `$` sign to subset your variable. Then, you tried to slice this output from the subset action using `[ , ]`, but it turned out that the output is a vector, and **a vector has always only one dimension** and an error was fired. You should slice your vector using `[]` (the output will be a vector) or `[[]]` (the output will be a vector with `length = 1`).

Possible ways to subset `tesla` as you wish:

```
tesla$abn.ret[tesla$period == "event.period"]
tesla[["abn.ret"]][tesla$period == "event.period"]
tesla[tesla$period == "event.period", "abn.ret"]
```

You would achieve the same result using `tesla[["period"]]` instead of `tesla$period`.

For some extra details/examples, refer to [An introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html), published by **CRAN**.

I hope it helped you somehow..!

Answer (score 0):

`tesla$abn.ret` is one-dimensional. Each comma separates a dimension, so yours implies 2 dimensions.

Alternatively you could run

```
tesla[tesla$period=="event.period", "abn.ret"]
```

And get the same results, since tesla is 2-d.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation with command `?'['`, you find that the default behaviour of syntax `x[i]` is to drop one dimension away.

If you want to disable the dropping of the dimension, you have explicitly to write `x[i,drop=False]`.